# Eclipse CDT Oxygen: Compiler issue

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt, toolchain

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and just opened my freshly installed Eclipse CDT Oxygen for the first time.

I imported an existing C++ project that builds fine using a CMake file that sets `add_definitions(-std=c++11)`.

I used CMake with the command `cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../src/` to generate Eclipse project files and then used those to import the project into Eclipse.

Now I'm looking at a source file in my newly imported project inside Eclipse and see a ton of issues. It's all types that cannot be resolved, for example `std::default_random_engine`.

My guess is that Eclipse doesn't have the right toolchain configured.

I have a few questions:

1. How can I see the toolchain for my project and how can I change it? I looked up [this](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_build_toolchain.htm) help article, but the sections in the project properties menu I see are not the same as in the help article. The project properties menu I see does not have a "C/C++ Build" section. How can that be?
2. The CMake file that I used to generate the Eclipse project files specifies that C++11 is supposed to be used, so why isn't this the case then?

Here is what my project properties menu looks like:

[image]

This is what my `.project` file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>particle_filter</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.genmakebuilder</name>
            <triggers>clean,full,incremental,</triggers>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ScannerConfigBuilder</name>
            <triggers>full,incremental,</triggers>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.managedBuildNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ScannerConfigNature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also in Eclipse Oxygen there should be a _C/C++ Build_ section in the project properties. Could you add a screenshot of your project's _Properties_ dialog to your question please.

Comment: @howlger I added a screenshot. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: What does your `.project` file look like?

Comment: Is the _C/C++ Build_ section also missing if you create a new project?

Comment: @howlger Thanks so much for your continued effort! I added the content of my `.project` file in my question. I also checked: When I create a new empty project, the "C/C++ Build" section does show up in the project properties.

Comment: `.project` looks good to me. Maybe the problem is caused by a broken `.cproject` file: What happens if you replace the `.cproject` file with the `.cproject` file of a new project?

Comment: @howlger One more thing though: Now there are no more compiler issues, all types can be resolved, all good. However, the project properties dialog for this project still looks like in the screenshot posted above. I don't understand why that is, given the content of the `.project` file I posted above and given that I took a `.cproject` file from a newly created project in which the project properties dialog looked as expected. Still I don't have the "C/C++ Build" section :/

Comment: See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **missing *C/C++ Build* section** can be caused by a **broken `.project`**, **`.cproject`** or  **`.settings/language.settings.xml`** file:

1. Create a **new project** of the same type
2. In the *Navigator* view **compare** the **`.project`**, the **`.cproject`** and the **`.settings/language.settings.xml`** files **with** the corresponding files of the **new project** to find the problem (make sure to use same IDs in `.cproject` and in `.settings/language.settings.xml`, but different IDs than in other projects)

Answer (score 1):

I think CMake's CDT project generator is fairly out of date and doesn't configure the generated project properly for C++11 support.

I recommend the following approach for configuring C++11 support:

- Go to `Project Properties | C/C++ General | Preprocessor Include Paths`.
- In the `Providers` tab, select `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings`.
- (If necessary, uncheck "Use global provider shared between projects".)
- Add `-std=c++11` to the "Command to get compiler specs".
- Apply and rebuild the project's index.

After doing this, C++11 symbols should be resolved properly.